# Can't connect to docker sql server from NET Core 2.2 Web API

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

While collecting knowledge of coding .NET Core Web API in combination with docker, I came across an error that I can't solve. I already did research on the internet, but somehow none of the provided solutions worked for me.

I have a web service called `Catalog.API` (similar to the eShopOnContainers project from Microsoft), where I have a controller called `CatalogController`.

This is the code from the controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Catalog.API.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Catalog.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CatalogController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CatalogItemContext _context;

        public CatalogController(CatalogItemContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<List<CatalogItem>> GetItemsAsync()
        {
            var items = await _context.CatalogItems.Where(model => model.Id < 10).ToListAsync();
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I only have one method that should return all items from an external database, that have an id smaller than 10.

The database is added in the `Startup.cs`:

```
namespace Catalog.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CatalogItemContext>(builder =>
            {
                builder.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
            });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

The `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Server=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=Test.Services.CatalogDb;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word" 
  }
}
```

To build this web service, I created a docker file that is called from the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Catalog.API.csproj /src/csproj-files/

WORKDIR ./csproj-files
RUN dotnet restore

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish

FROM base as final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Catalog.API.dll"]
```

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  sqldata:
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word

  catalog.api:
    ports:
      - 80:80
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - sqldata
```

As already mentioned, in addition to the Catalog.API web service, I am also running a SQL Server database inside a docker container. For development purposes, I am connecting to this SQL Server from DataGrip using localhost or my machine ip as the host address (`localhost` or `192.168.2.101`). Both ways work fine and I can establish a connection inside DataGrip without a problem.

My problem is that I can not connect to SQL Server from inside the docker container in my `CatalogController`, running on localhost:80. Normally, when I call `localhost:80/api/catalog`, I should get all items out of the database (see the controller at the beginning), but somehow, I get this error:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
>   An error occurred using the connection to database 'Test.Services.CatalogDb' on server 'localhost,1433'.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>       ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

I already tried to use serveral ips (localhost, my machine ip + the ip out of docker inspect), but none is working.

```
Server=192.168.2.101,1433;Initial Catalog=Test.Services.CatalogDb;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word
```

I am open for every help, that can solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both docker services need to be within the same [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/)

Comment: Issue is with your connection string `An error occurred using the connection to database 'Test.Services.CatalogDb' on server 'localhost,1433'`.Add : in Server name, you have added comma. `Server=localhost:1433;`  Everything looks fine.

Comment: Docker containers can access each other in the same network by service name. You can change 'localhost,1433' to 'sqldata'

Comment: Before diving into the .net code, can you connect from the command line?  e.g. `sqlcmd -S localhost,1433` ?

Comment: @JinnaBalu: The comma is fine. It has to be there instead of a :.

Comment: @A. van Hugten: Adding the service name instead of the IP works, but whenever i migrate the database using "dotnet ef migrations add xyz" and "dotnet ef database update", i get an error. It says, server not found or not accessible.. So now i can connect, but cannot use dotnet ef..

Comment: @user1443098 : Yes, i can connect from the command line. Also from DataGrip itself, but not from the .NET Core Web Api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQL Server instance is not on localhost. In the context of the web app, localhost is the container the web app is running in, which is not the same container that SQL Server is in.

When using Docker Compose, the service names end up as hostnames, which means that you can simply connect to `sqldata,1433`.

> Adding the service name instead of the IP works, but whenever i migrate the database using "dotnet ef migrations add xyz" and "dotnet ef database update", i get an error. It says, server not found or not accessible.. So now i can connect, but cannot use dotnet ef.

The hostname is only valid within the vlan that your docker containers are running in, which is not the same vlan your desktop machine is in. To access the SQL Server container, you must either `docker container exec` into one of the containers and run the commands from there (where the `sqldata` hostname will exist) or you must use the IP address of the container, which you can get by running `docker container ls` to get the container id (guid) and then run `docker inspect {container id}`. The IP address will be in the `NetworkSettings` section of the resulting JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i also came across this while researching this error but i wasnt able to solve this. Using the service name as a hostname works. But now, whenever i use dotnet ef migrations add xyz and dotnet ef database update, i get an error that says, database not found or not accessible. So, now the connection is possible but i cannot use dotnet ef anymore..

Comment: Also thank you for the edit regarding dotnet ef. I did follow your second part regarding docker inspect to get the ip address of the container. After retrieving the IP of the docker container once again, i pasted it into the connection string and it seems to work. I already did this before but somehow, it didnt work. Anyways, now it is working. Thank you

Comment: Well, the IP is not constant, so it's not something you should really persist in something like `appsettings.json`. You can pass the connection string along with the `dotnet ef` commands, though.

Comment: Good point. Whats the best way to pass the connection string along with the dotnet ef commands?

Comment: Sorry. I'm thinking of the `scaffold` command. The others don't support that. The main problem here is that this is really not how you should be handling things (half in/half out of the containers). Ideally, the image build should output a SQL script or DACPAC which you can then apply to the SQL Server container at startup of the container, using a custom entry point. There's guides online, but it's too complicated to go into here.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks man, you saved my day! You made me understand of this "network" stuff works within docker-compose, didn't know it created a sort of internal vlan with hostnames mapped as set in the docker-compose.yml. Thanks!